# using unicode in python for Farsi

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I'm writing a script to read from a corpus file and find suffixes. Since there are Persian words in the corpus it is UTF-8 encoded, however when I use Persian suffixes for searching I get no results, English results on the other hand back fine.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import nltk
import sys


for line in open("corpus.txt"):
for word in line.split():
     if word.endswith('ب'):
        print (word)
```

Comment: What you mean by *i get no results* ?

Comment: and whats your python version? (it seems that you are in python 3 ) but i need to be sure!

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4, and I actually get no results in shell as if there are no words in corpus,  @Kasra

Comment: In python 3 you don't need `from __future__ import unicode_literals` too , and your code will works well! but do you have any word in your file that ends with `ب` ?

Comment: I had imported 'from __future__ import unicode_literals ' but it doesn't work, and I do have words ending in "b". anyways opening file as UTF-8 'with open("corpus.txt", encoding="utf-8") as fp:' worked for me.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39528462/5284370) out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 3, you can just pass `encoding=utf-8` to `open`:

```
with open("corpus.txt", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        for word in line.split():
            process(word)
```

In Python 2, you'll need to do something like this:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("corpus.txt", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        for word in line.split():
            process(word)
```